# Can two accounts be unmerged?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I wanted to change the email address for my account, and I have typed in the new email and clicked send verification email button.

It turns out the new email I typed in belongs to an old Stack Overflow account of mine, which I had forgotten the password to and didn't request a new password.

Apparently, Stack Overflow merges two accounts with the same email. I wasn't aware of this. I thought it would say **this email is already taken** or something.

By any change, can I unmerge these two accounts?

Comment: That should be possible. I think I've seen an accidental merge undone, in the past.